# C# Onpaint is not firing

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code:

```
    private void HandleGUI()
    {
        if (_currentForm == null)
        {
            navigationSideBar1.Visible = false;
            pnlToolbar.Visible = false;

            return;
        }

        if (_currentForm.ShowNavigationBar)
        {
            HandleNavigationButton(_currentForm);
        }

        btnSave.Visible = _currentForm.ShowSaveButton;
        btnClose.Visible = _currentForm.ShowCloseButton;
        btnSave.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(btnSave_Paint);
        navigationSideBar1.Visible = _currentForm.ShowNavigationBar;
        pnlToolbar.Visible = _currentForm.ShowToolBar;

        btnSave.Refresh();
        btnSave.Invalidate();
    }
```

I am registered on the onpaint event of the save button (btnSave), but this event is not fired, even when I call Refresh or Invalidate. How is this possible?

EDIT:
This is how the saave button class looks like:

```
public class SaveButton : ButtonX
{
    public SaveButton()
    {
        this.Image = Properties.Resources.Save;
        this.Text = "Opslaan";
        this.Size = new Size(108, 39);

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a standard button, or a custom control?

Comment: That's not normal.  Probably have to see the Paint event.  Are you overriding it maybe?

Comment: Hard to guess when this code might be called.  Random shot: the button isn't visible (yet).

Comment: I'd guess it's already been painted before this code is called, but I may be mixing this up with how iOS does things.

Comment: This is a custom button which inherits from buttonX, which is a DevComponent button.

Comment: You should edit your question and tags to reflect that it's not a standard button.  It is relevant for you to get a resolution.

Comment: Have you added the button to the form? Is it visible? Is it placed in a visible area? Where is this code being called? You need to provide more info.

Comment: Try adding a regular DevComponent button (i.e. not a subclass of it) to a test form and see if it ever fires its `Paint` event. They may have exposed a Paint event (so that their interface matches that of a regular button) but not actually implemented it.

Comment: Everybody thanks for the comments. It has something to do with the devComponents button. I've tried the same code with a system button, and then it is working just fine.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: I have override the OnPaint event in the class, and still nothing happens, so I guess you're right with the thought that the event doesn't have an implementation.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: can you post an answer so I can mark your answer as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a regular DevComponent button (i.e. not a subclass of it) to a test form and see if it ever fires its Paint event. They may have exposed a Paint event (so that their interface matches that of a regular button) but not actually implemented it.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `userpaint` to `true` will fire the `onpaint` event

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx):

> Calling the Invalidate method does not force a synchronous paint; to force a synchronous paint, call the Update method after calling the Invalidate method.

So, you need an Update call.  Now, Refresh is just Invalidate w/ update children + Update, so theoretically you're taken care of.  All I can think is that Windows doesn't call Paint unless it really needs to, ie when the form is shown on the UI or written to a graphics device ("screenshot" of an invisible window).  Are either of these the case?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not calling the base class constructor in the constructor of your `SaveButton` component.

```
public class SaveButton : ButtonX
{
    public SaveButton() : base()
...
```